# How does $V \geqslant I$ imply that $V$ is invertible?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am reading the proof of Hildebrandt's theorem in [these](https://pskoufra.info.yorku.ca/files/2016/07/Numerical-Range.pdf) notes by Paul Skoufranis. The proof of Proposition $4.1$ (Rota's theorem) on Pg. $13$ says that:

> Moreover, we notice that $T^*VT = V - I$. Thus, since $T^*VT \geqslant 0$, $V \geqslant I$, so $V$ is invertible.

I am unable to understand how $V \geqslant I$ implies that $V$ is invertible, could someone please explain?

---

I have tried to use the Riesz Representation Theorem. Consider $f: \mathcal H\times \mathcal H \to \mathcal H$ given by $f(x,y) = \langle Vx,y\rangle$. We know that $V \geqslant I$, so that $f(x,x) \ge \langle Vx,x\rangle \ge \|x\|^2$ for all $x\in \mathcal H$. Now, fix $x\in \mathcal H$, and consider the functional $f(x, \cdot): y\mapsto f(x,y) = \langle Vx,y\rangle$. By the Riesz Representation Theorem, there exists some $X \in \mathcal H$ (dependent on $x$) such that
$$\langle Vx, y\rangle = \langle X,y\rangle$$
for all $y\in \mathcal H$. I am inclined to define $V^{-1}X := x$, but I do not know if I can define the action of $V^{-1}$ on *every element* of the Hilbert space in this manner, and if this is even well-defined.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you write $V = R^*R$ for some $R \ge I$?  If so, then $\|Rx\|^2 = \langle Vx, x \rangle \ge \|x\|^2 > 0$ whenever $x \ne 0$, so that $R$ (and hence $V$) is invertible.

Comment: Maybe: the spectrum of $V-I$ is contained in $[0,+\infty)$, so the spectrum of $V$ is contained in $[1,+\infty)$.  Therefore, $0$ is not in the spectrum of $V$.  Hence $V$ is invertible.

Comment: $\|Vx\|\|x\|\geq\langle Vx,x\rangle\geq \langle x,x\rangle = \|x\|^2$ so $\|Vx\|\geq\|x\|$.  Now use that $V$ is self adjoining to conclude it is onto.